# Conversion from int to date datatype in hana SQL table definition

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, hana

I have imported a `csv` file to sap hana, the `date` column datatype is maintained as `int` at hana table definition. I would like to change the data type from `int` to `date` and would like to apply changes to records accordingly.

Comment: and if its int how the date values are getting stored ?

Comment: Did you try something?

Answer (score 0):

If the `date` column has values in `int` form, they must be in the `unix_timestamp` form.

If you want to convert the column to `date` or `datetime` data type, you better add a new column with required data type. And then update the column as selected from old `int` column. Lastly you can drop the `int` column, and start using `date` type column.

```
-- add new datetime type column
ALTER TABLE table_name
  ADD COLUMN date_col_new_name DATETIME;

-- add values into the same column
-- read from int type date column
UPDATE table_name
   SET date_col_new_name = FROM_UNIXTIME( int_type_date_col );

-- now drop the int type date column
ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN int_type_date_col;
```

**Example**: On `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` and `FROM_UNIXTIME`:

```
mysql> drop table if exists ut_xmple;
mysql> create table ut_xmple( date int );
mysql> insert into ut_xmple( date ) values ( unix_timestamp() );
mysql> select * from ut_xmple;
+------------+
| date       |
+------------+
| 1399536302 |
+------------+

mysql> alter table ut_xmple add column date_time datetime;
mysql> select * from ut_xmple;
+------------+-----------+
| date       | date_time |
+------------+-----------+
| 1399536302 | NULL      |
+------------+-----------+

mysql> update ut_xmple set date_time=from_unixtime( date );
mysql> select * from ut_xmple;
+------------+---------------------+
| date       | date_time           |
+------------+---------------------+
| 1399536302 | 2014-05-08 13:35:02 |
+------------+---------------------+

mysql> select now(), @ut:=unix_timestamp() ut, from_unixtime( @ut ) fut;
+---------------------+------------+---------------------+
| now()               | ut         | fut                 |
+---------------------+------------+---------------------+
| 2014-05-08 13:35:54 | 1399536354 | 2014-05-08 13:35:54 |
+---------------------+------------+---------------------+
```

**Refer to**:

- [UNIX_TIMESTAMP()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp),
- [UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp)
- [FROM_UNIXTIME(unix_timestamp)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime),
- [FROM_UNIXTIME(unix_timestamp,format)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)

Comment: Hi Ravinder, the values in date coloumn are in below pattern 20,110,113-record 1
20,110,213-record 2
20,110,122-record 3
20,110,115-record 4    in data definition of table i can see column store data type of date column as int.I am maintaining only dates in this field,no time.